# NightwatchJS never runs the url

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I have been trying to configure nightwatch to perform some unittesting tasks.

Selenium server and chrome are running but I never get the url actually loading in the url bar in chrome, thus nothing appears, I just get a blank white page with "data;" in the url in chrome (using chromedirver)

Here's my configuration if someone can help

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["test"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",
  "live_output" : true,
  "parallel_process_delay" : 10,
  "disable_colors": false,
  "test_workers" : false,

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "bin/selenium.jar",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "bin/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "bin/geckodriver"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "test_link.com",
      "selenium_host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port" : 4444,
      "silent" : true,
      "disable_colors": false,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities" : {
        "browserName" : "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true
      }
    },

    "saucelabs" : {
      "selenium_host" : "ondemand.saucelabs.com",
      "selenium_port" : 80,
      "username" : "${SAUCE_USERNAME}",
      "access_key" : "${SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY}",
      "use_ssl" : false,
      "silent" : true,
      "output" : true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "on_failure" : true,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "name" : "test-example",
        "browserName": "firefox"
      },
      "globals" : {
        "myGlobal" : "some_sauce_global"
      },
      "selenium" : {
        "start_process" : false
      }
    },


    "testingbot" : {
      "selenium_host" : "hub.testingbot.com",
      "selenium_port" : 80,
      "apiKey" : "${TB_KEY}",
      "apiSecret" : "${TB_SECRET}",
      "silent" : true,
      "output" : true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "on_failure" : true,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "name" : "test-example",
        "browserName": "firefox"
      },
      "selenium" : {
        "start_process" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here's my test

```
module.exports = {
  'Tracking the website': function (client) 

    client
      .url(client.launch_url)
      .getValue('#id1', function(result){
        console.log("================================");
        console.log("value " + result.value);
        console.log("================================");
      })
      .end();
  }
};
```

Comment: @fOunix Does the answer of *ralph-mayr* below resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `launch_url` doesn't contain the protocol to use.

Try using `"launch_url" : "http://www.google.com"` instead of `"launch_url" : "www.google.com"`.

Comment: @ralph-mayr I found your answer helpfull. Using `http://google.com` instead of `www.google.com` fix the issue.

Comment: @AlaEddineJEBALI I've tried it many times. Apparently when I test it on a unix based system different than osx, it works just fine ! On my osx I am never getting the ability to lauch or observe any web automation which is a little fuzzy, since I'm not able to identify what is the actual problem. Perhaps it's in the way browser drivers work, or something else.